# How to modify $_SESSION var dynamically using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I'm developing a website which allow the user to do query on a public database and I would like to allow the user to see the query he has done during the current session and delete one of them he wants to.

here is the code creating `$_SESSION['history']`:

```
$_SESSION['history'][] = array(
    'Database' => $_SESSION['db'],
    'Choice' => $_SESSION['radio'],
    'Query' => $_SESSION['query'],
    'Résult' => ($asResults),
    'Date' =>  date("d-m-Y"),
    'Hour' => date("H:i:s")     
);
```

here is the code displaying the array of the $_SESSION['history']:

```
<?php
function displayHistory($arQueryArray)
{
if (isset($_SESSION['history']))
{
    echo '<table id="history" class="display">';
    $iQueryNumber = 0;

    echo '<thead><tr>';
    echo '<th>n°</th>';
    foreach (array_keys($_SESSION['history'][0]) as $field)
    {
        if ($field != 'Résult' and $field != 'Choice')
            {
                echo '<th>', $field, '</th>';
            }
    }
    echo '<th></th><th></th>';
    echo '</tr></thead>';

    echo '<tbody>';
    foreach ($_SESSION['history'] as $query) 
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>', ($iQueryNumber + 1), '</td>';
        foreach ($query as $field => $value) 
        {
            if ($field != 'Résult' and $field != 'Choice' and $field != 'Requête')
            {
                echo '<td>', $value, '</td>';
            }
            else if ($field == 'Query')
            {
                echo '<td>' . $arQueryArray[$query['Choice']] . " " . $query['Query'] . '</td>';
            }
        }
        ?>
        <td>
        <input type="button" class="del_btn" value="X" title="Delete this query" onclick="delQueryInHistory(<?php echo $iQueryNumber; ?>, this);"/>
        </td>
        <?php
        echo '</tr>';
        $iQueryNumber += 1;
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
else
{
    echo "<p>No query</p>";
}
}
?>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var XHR = null;


function getXMLHTTP()
{
    var xhr = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { // Firefox 
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    { // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1)
            {
                xhr = null;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    { // XMLHttpRequest not supported
        alert("YOur browser doesn't support XMLHTTPRequest...");
    }

    return xhr;
}


//Query suppression function
function delQueryInHistory(queryId, self)
{
    XHR = getXMLHTTP();

XHR.open("GET", "controleur/delQueryInHistory.php?queryId=" + queryId, true);

XHR.onreadystatechange = function()
{

    if (XHR.readyState == 4)
    { 
self.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(self.parentNode.parentNode);
    }
}
XHR.send();
}
```

Here is the php called

```
    <?php
session_start();

if(empty($_GET['queryId']) or !is_numeric($_GET['queryId']) or !isset($_GET['queryId']))
{
    exit;
}
else
{
    unset($_SESSION['history'][intval($_GET['queryId'])]);
} 
?>
```

The problem is that it simply doesn't run and i don't understand why since i have not any error raised! Even if i use a corrupted php file... I have already verified that the path to the php file is OK!

Sorry for my English, and thanks..

** Last UPDATE:** Sorry, I've forgotten to say what specially didn't run: The row is correctly removed but the $_SESSION['history'][queryId] is not removed! But the `XmlHttp` object has been created! Thanks.

Comment: Which bit doesn't work? The page doesn't load, the XHR doesn't fire, the XHR fires but doesn't remove the row, the XHR fires but the session value doesn't change?

Comment: I've modified my post, thanks!

Comment: Your `if..else` may be falling into the wrong condition. In your PHP output things that you can debug, e.g. rather than just `exit;`ing, return the input and the result of each test condition so you can debug it.    

Then look in your console at the content returned by the _XHR_ (it will be in the _Network_ tab if log xhr's isn't ticked in the _Console_ tab) so you can see exactly what is happening

Comment: Thank You Paul S! The issue wasn't in the if..else but your tip helped me a lot to solve my problem (unset() doesn't normalize integer keys and i don't understand well why, but when i've fixed it, everything has been OK) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to fix the issue, maybe it could help

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_GET['queryId']) or !is_numeric($_GET['queryId']) or !isset($_GET['queryId']))
{
    exit;
}
else
{
    unset($_SESSION['history'][$_GET['queryId']]);
    $_SESSION['history'] = array_values($_SESSION['history']);
} 
?>
```

the unset() function doesn't normalize integer indexes and it broke my code during the display!